# Mutliple controllers are being loaded when switching views (manually compiled)

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to integrate some angular into our MVC application. This is requiring some slightly more in-depth knowledge of how angular compiles the DOM, but it doesn't *seem* unachievable.

[Here's a link to the CodePen](http://codepen.io/mortware/pen/dvOVaq)

Essentially, I have a bunch of code (that I can't touch) which controls the page being loaded into DOM. This uses JQuery.

What I have is an `ng-include` that loads in a template, which gives me my 'angularised' DOM. Because this element is loaded in via AJAX, I'm having to manually `$compile` it when its inserted.

This is works okay until I switch to a different view, and then back again. The controller is instantiated again (as expected), but the previous one is still responding to the event.

I think I need to `$destroy` the old controller and all its child scopes, but how do I obtain them?

Comment: console shows logs with ContactID 1 and 2 when clicked on them respectively. What behavior exactly is required?

Comment: If you keep clicking on the different menu items, you will start to see the console log reporting multiple "Loading items for...". I need it to only log it *once* for the Contact you just clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

What you were missing is destroying the event listener `$scope.$on(notifyRefreshEvent, ...` and you do that by doing something like this. Here's your `EventService` snippet which solves this issue:

```
app.service('EventService', function($rootScope){
  var notifyRefreshEvent = "contact::refresh";
  var eventListenerDestroy;

  return {
    ...
  }

  ...

  function onContactRefresh($scope, handler) {
    eventListenerDestroy = $scope.$on(notifyRefreshEvent, function (e, data) {
      eventListenerDestroy(); // this guy destroys it
      handler(data);
    });
  }
});
```

Also, here's the [forked codepen solution](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/xqRNXd?editors=1011)

Comment: Would that mean that the controller is still alive and kicking, but simply not responding to this particular event? I know there is no DOM for it anymore, but my problem would suggest that it will stay alive forever...

Comment: Yes, it means controller is there (AFAIK) but it no longer listens to your event emission. I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6185) for removal of controller but frankly it would be too dirty a solution even if we are able to remove it.

Comment: @mortware But, if you `console.log` inside controller directly, it logs only once. So, I think what I said above might be wrong. It could just be listening to event since it was on `$rootScope` and controllers are gone with the DOM

Comment: @mortware I actually asked to few peers of mine and found that controllers are gone with the DOM but the case here was with listeners on event which were not destroyed because they were bound to rootscope. So, what we did in answer is the right solution! :)